# How to disable any line-break changing auto-formatting behavior in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio's auto-formatting feature is quite useful in itself. However, it changes line breaks, which makes it difficult to find significant changes when comparing different versions of a source file in version control.

Is there a way to set it to affect only inline indentation and whitespace (which are filtered by modern compare tools)? I found some settings in 'Tools / Options / Text Editor / C# / Formatting / New Lines', but those only change how the code is formatted, they don't disable the behavior altogether.

Cheers,
Sandor

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you need, but in **[File - Advanced Save Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409797.aspx)** you can configure the line endings that Visual Studio will apply when saving files. Thus, you can at least get a consistent behavior when saving.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the line-breaking behavior that I'd like to disable. Nice to know though.